# ASP:CustomValidator continues to execute after error message thrown

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, customvalidator

ASP:CustomValidator continues to execute the rest of my code after the the Validator renders as False. I have a few textboxes (Name, Date, IdNumber, OtherShit)
Here's some code:

```
<span class="grouping" id="span1" runat="server">
    <label>
        ID Number</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbIdNumber" runat="server" MaxLength="6" Columns="10"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorIdNumber" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter date."
        ControlToValidate="tbIdNumber" OnServerValidate="CustomValidatorLocation_ServerValidate1">&nbsp;</asp:CustomValidator>
</span>
```

Followed by the back end code controlling the Validator:

```
Protected Sub CustomValidatorLocation_ServerValidate1(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles CustomValidatorIdNumber.ServerValidate
        Dim currentUserId = Things.AuthenticatedData.Get_CurrentUser.Id

        If (Convert.ToString(args.Value)) Is currentUserId Then
            args.IsValid = True
        ElseIf (Convert.ToString(args.Value)) IsNot currentUserId And bdpDate.IsNull Then
            args.IsValid = False
        End If
    End Sub
```

So each person logged in has an ID that is known to other users. FYI this is a search filter. Basically what I would like to do is this: if the user types in their own ID, then everything is fine and will continue to execute through the code. If the user types in another users ID, they also need to include a date. If no date is include, it throws the error message when they click "Search" (but does not execute the search) until they put in a date. Currently it does all that, but still executes the search. Meh... Help please...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put the Page.IsValid() on the right instance of the btnClick... fml. Works perfect now.